# Detecting whether or not user has created an account from a unique device on an app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, mobile, expo

We are developing a mobile app that uses Firebase authentication. The app is written in react-native and we use generic Java spring boot BE. Right now we only use email for registration and email verification to complete user registration.

I was wondering if there is any way we could verify the device on which the user was created to prevent people from making a lot of fake emails and fake accounts on the same device. There is a possibility in Firebase to send a SMS message with a code, but that would be expensive in the long term as we are just launching the app. Are there any other ways or is this most probably the only way to be sure?

Comment: I don't think this question really pertains to spring, java, or even react-native.  You'll probably have better success asking in the android, ios, or mobile space.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing a unique id specific to the device first in somewhere like firestore, and cross check that on required places ?

On Android you can get a device unique Id via [`getAndroidId`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidenterprise/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidenterprise/model/Device.html#getAndroidId--)

If its react native you can use `react-native-device-info`'s [`getUniqueId`](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid) API